# how to integrate $f(x)= \int \frac{e^{-x}}{\sin^{11/3}x\times \cos^{1/3}x} dx$

Tags: integration, limits

actually the question is

> $$ f(x)=\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} e^{x\tan{(1/n)\log(1/n)}}$$  then find $$R=\int \frac{f(x)}{\sin^{11/3}x\times \cos^{1/3}x} dx$$

so$$f(x)=\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} e^{-x\log(n^{\tan{(1/n)}})}=\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}e^{-x\times I}\implies$$

$$I=\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\log(n^{\tan(1/n)})\implies e^I=\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}n^{tan(1/n)}\text{ (a problem of  } \infty^0)$$
$$\therefore e^I=e^{\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\tan({1/n})\times(n-1)}\implies I=\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\tan\left(\frac 1n\right )(n-1)$$
let $n=\frac 1h$
$$\implies I=\lim_{h\rightarrow 0}\tan(h)\left(\frac 1h-1 \right)=\lim_{h\rightarrow 0}\frac {\tan(h)}{h} (1-h)=1\implies f(x)=e^{-x}$$
$$R=\int \frac{e^{-x}}{\sin^{11/3}x\times \cos^{1/3}x} dx$$

what i have tries is as follows:

multiply numerator and denominator by  $\cos^{11/3}x$
$$R=\int \frac{e^{-x}\cos^{11/3}x}{\sin^{11/3}x\times \cos^{1/3}x\cos^{11/3}x} dx=\int{e^{-x}\cot^{11/3}x\sec^4x}dx=\int{e^{-x}\cot^{11/3}x(1+\tan^4x+2\tan^2x)}dx$$$$=\int e^{-x}\cot^{11/3}xdx+\int e^{-x}\cot^{-1/3}x +2\int e^{-x}\cot^{5/3}xdx$$

you can see that this made this more complicated, i don't know how to solve this, i can could use integration by parts but it would make the problem more complicated and harder to solve. so i thought to drop this idea and then what i did was put $\tan x=u$ but still i couldn't find the value of R.

So there should be some other method which i think i don't know, or is my limit evaluation is wrong ? How do i evaluate this integration?

Comment: $\tan (1/n)\sim 1/n$ as $n\to\infty$, and $\log (1/n)=-\log n$. And $\dfrac{\log n}{n}\to 0$.

Comment: In your question, you have made a mistake: after transforming $\tan(1/n)\log(1/n)$ into a power, you are transforming back to a log, but the log didn't reappear, you wrote $\tan(1/n)\times(n-1)$ instead of $\tan(1/n)\times\log(n)$, hence your limit is wrong.